# CD\ROM driver won't start

Tags: windows-7, windows, hard-drive, compact-disc

CD ROM won't start in Windows 7, Dell Inspiron 530S.  It shows up in Device Manager, but not under Computer.  Can't read DVD.

Can you suggest how to enable this please?

Comment: In Device Manager, does the device entry show any errors?

Comment: If it's really a CD-ROM, then you won't be able to read DVDs.  Have you tried booting from it?

Answer (score 1):

I've had this problem many times on different computer brands. It's usually nothing more than a simple [registry fix](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/314060).

Click Start
Type `regedit`
`regedit` will appear at the top of of the menu. Right that, and click `Run as administrator`.
In the navigation pane, go to the subkey `"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4D36E965-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}"`
In the right pane, there are two keys named `UpperFilters` and `LowerFilters`. Delete them. Don't delete or modify anything else in that menu.
Close the registry editor, and restart the computer. Your disk drive should now be working as expected.